# Getting list with one element stored at each cell after adding array.tolist() to a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I had **np.ndarray** elements like the one mentioned below to be added to a pandas dataframe as columns.

Original array -->

```
nparray = [[0.8986785 , 0.70790794, 0.67611285]]
```

So I used the following syntax:

```
df_test['column1'] = nparray.tolist()
```

I was expecting resulting dataframe to look like this:

```
|   | column1   |
| --| --------- |
| 0 | 0.8986785 |
| 1 | 0.70790794|
| 2 | 0.67611285|
```

But instead I got a every element of dataframe as a list with one element as follows:

```
|   | column1     |
| --| ----------- |
| 0 | [0.8986785] |
| 1 | [0.70790794]|
| 2 | [0.67611285]|
```

How can I modify the code to get expected output?
Kindly help.

Comment: You can not expect that output because it's a 2D array/list, you can just explode the column after assignment. `df_test['column1'] = df_test['column1'].explode()`

Comment: I'm unclear on the structure of these types because `nparray = np.array([[0.8986785, 0.70790794, 0.67611285]])` then `df_test['column1'] = nparray.tolist()` gave me 1 row in a dataframe `0  [0.8986785, 0.70790794, 0.67611285]`

Comment: I think that you are assigning like that `df_test['column1']=nparray.T.tolist()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `flatten()`:

```
df_test['column1'] = nparray.flatten()
```

OR

with `ravel()`:

```
df_test['column1'] = nparray.ravel()
```

since you have a 2D array so make it 1D via `flatten()`**/**`ravel()` and then assign